# OAuth2 with Gmail API - Redirect

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, desktop-application

As Google will disable the "Less secure app access" option, I'm implementing a Windows Forms Application (.NET Framework) for sending emails with OAuth. I logged into the Google Developers Console and created a "Desktop" type credential. When running my application I am redirected to the

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=...apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A62437%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.send&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

I log in and the email is sent, but after logging in, I am redirected to the

> http://127.0.0.1:56332/authorize/?code=somecode&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send

Is there a way to not do this redirection? I don't need it. If required, can I change this uri? It doesn't make sense for me to redirect to 127.0.01, as it's the address of my client's machine, which has a desktop application installed.

Comment: no the user needs to be shown the consent screen.  The redirection is what is returning the authorizaotn code to you.  Without that you have no way to get access.   If you are using the .net client library it should be handling this for you.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you, desktop WinForms app implementing authorization, and the redirect uri is localhost, it is ugly for the end user. Have you found a solution?